# LaTeX bug or else?

Tags: support, mathjax

In [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428689/rees-algebra-of-a-monomial-ideal) I can't see the reason for some indices looks like not being indices. I've done something wrong or is there a LaTeX bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it. For some reason you typed an ["empty" character](https://www.google.com/search?q=zero+width+character) between the underscore `_` and the `q`. So the action of the underscore hit the empty character instead of the letter `q`.

Removing the zero-width character fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Actually wasn't me, I just copied a question of someone else, but for some reason I didn't see that empty character.

Comment: @YACP: can't blame you for not seeing, since that is the whole point of a zero-width character...

Comment: The original post by fbakhshi was riddled with `\unicode{0x200E}` characters (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK). I removed the rest from YACP's post.